# How does the system environment influence itextsharp (newline) rendering?

Tags: pdf, itext, windows-server-2012-r2

After some years of creating pdf documents with itextsharp, I though I'd be the one helping people with their itext questions here - but now I got one myself, that I'm stuck with:

The problem is, that with the **same source code, same itextsharp dll and the same template/data** the pdf on a productive environment renders slighly different than on the dev/staging environment.

While the linespacing within a paragraph is the same in both documents, the space between two paragraphs (+empty line) is slightly higher on production. This tiny difference is summing up over the paragraphs in the document and leads to a unwanted line/page break at the end of the document.

Since in my implementation there is a whole framework around the itextsharp lib, generating pdfs from xml templates and database data, I cannot simply provide "the code" generating the pdfs.

Basically a template definition like:

```
<text>Hello</text>
<text />
<text>World</text>
```

...would result in a code processing like:

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello", font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Chunk c = Chunk.NEWLINE;
c.Font = font;
p.Add(c);
document.Add(p);
document.Add(new Paragraph("World", font);
```

The font for each paragraph is created like:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font(
    BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false),       
    Size, 
    Style, 
    Color);
```

There are no chapters, sections, tables or outer paragraphs wrapped around the text. There is no DirectContent rendering in the immediate area of the text.

Both productive and staging environments are 2008 R2 servers with (as far as I know) identical setup and installed applications. The pdf creating component is an aspx webservice delivering the binary pdf.

The itextsharp lib used is v4.1.6.0 (unfortunately I am bound to this version atm)

So what in the seven hells would cause a higher distance between "Hello" and "World" on one environment than on the other?

Any idea on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the fonts are not exectly the same, even if they have the same name check the version. Given the same fonts it will render exactly the same in any environment.

Comment: Does the "HELVETICA" BaseFont actually use the Arial Regular from windows fonts? (-> This font is the same version on both environments)
But since the embedded-Option is set to false, the Pdf Reader displaying the pdf would use the client systems font, will it not?

Comment: HELVETICA will use the same metrics everywhere, the rendering will use what the viewer chooses. This will never result in the incremental error you say it happens. It's better that you post both PDFs so that they can be inspected.

Comment: The pdfs content is confidential. In which way can the pdfs be inspected?
I was able to run the genator on production in a console application, using productions DLLs. The Hello World pdf with the code above and a pdf generated from the original template (just without the database content) did NOT show the error.  :(

Comment: Without looking at both PDFs your question is unanswerable.